# Trouble adding 'active' class to entire list of <p>, only adds it to first 7 items

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem

I have a small navigation containing seven pets names, a scroll listener is checking to see how far a person scrolls down the page. It then and adds a class of `active` to `<p class="nameNav>` when the person scrolls to that pet and points to expanded adoption information.

However, this active class is only being added to the first seven items in the navigation, not all forty and I'm wondering if it's because of problems with the scroll listener or how `var index=` has been declared.

## JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jja9vecc/

## scripts.js

```
$(function(){
      // Deals with loading the pets
      var public_spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TOIGfwdi1GhV7BMhc5fH481icHi7zEEyXZZx3Y5J61I/pubhtml";

      $(document).ready( function() {
        Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
            callback: showInfo,
            parseNumbers: true } );
      });
      function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        var source   = $("#pets").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        // The actual name of the sheet, not entire .csv
        $.each(tabletop.sheets("Pets").all(), function(i, fact) {
            var html = template(fact);

          // You need an element with this id or class in your HTML
          $("#pets-list").append(html);
          $('.container').eq(i).addClass(data.Pets.elements[i]);
          // console.log(data.Pets.elements[i].name);

            // Deals with the left menu
            $(".nameNav").click(function(){
               $(".nameNav").removeClass("active");
               $(this).toggleClass("active");
            });

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var $pets = $('.pet').map(function(_, i){
                    return $(i).offset().top;
                });

                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                  var index = $pets.filter(function(i, v){ if(v < scroll) return i; }).length;
                  $(".nameNav").removeClass("active");
                  $(".nameNav").eq(index).addClass("active");
                  // console.log(index);

                  if (index >= 7 && index <= 13) {
                     $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[7].name);
                     $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[8].name);
                     $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[9].name);
                     $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[10].name);
                     $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[11].name);
                     $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[12].name);
                     $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[13].name);
                  } else if (index >= 14 && index <= 20) {
                     $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[14].name);
                     $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[15].name);
                     $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[16].name);
                     $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[17].name);
                     $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[18].name);
                     $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[19].name);
                     $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[20].name);
                  } else if (index >= 21 && index <= 27) {
                    $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[21].name);
                    $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[22].name);
                    $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[23].name);
                    $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[24].name);
                    $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[25].name);
                    $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[26].name);
                    $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[27].name);
                  } else if (index >= 28 && index <= 34) {
                    $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[28].name);
                    $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[29].name);
                    $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[30].name);
                    $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[31].name);
                    $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[32].name);
                    $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[33].name);
                    $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[34].name);
                  } else if (index >= 35 && index <= 38) {
                    $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[35].name);
                    $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[36].name);
                    $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[37].name);
                    $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[38].name);
                  } else {
                    $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[0].name);
                    $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[1].name);
                    $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[2].name);
                    $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[3].name);
                    $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[4].name);
                    $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[5].name);
                    $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[6].name);
                  }

                  if (index >= 35 && index <= 38) {
                    $(".fifth").addClass("hide");
                    $(".sixth").addClass("hide");
                    $(".seventh").addClass("hide");
                  } else {
                    $(".fifth").removeClass("hide");
                    $(".sixth").removeClass("hide");
                    $(".seventh").removeClass("hide");
                  }
      });
    });
    };
});
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Name of Website</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="vertical">
        <div class="rectangle">
            <a href="#Adonis"><p class="nameNav first active">Adonis</p></a>
            <a href="#Billy"><p class="nameNav second">Billy</p></a>
            <a href="#Comet"><p class="nameNav third">Comet</p></a>
            <a href="#Dexter"><p class="nameNav fourth">Dexter</p></a>
            <a href="#Evan"><p class="nameNav fifth">Evan</p></a>
            <a href="#Fritz"><p class="nameNav sixth">Fritz</p></a>
            <a href="#Grommit"><p class="nameNav seventh">Grommit</p></a>
        </div><!-- /.rectangle -->
    </nav>

    <main>
        <div id="pets-list"></div>
    </main>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.3.5/tabletop.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>

        <!-- This is where the template for facts goes -->
        <script id="pets" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="pet">
                    <p class="nameTitle" id="{{name}}">{{name}}</p>
                    <img src="{{image}}" alt="">
                    <p class="breed">{{breed}}</p>
                    <p class="description">{{description}}</p>
                    <p class="cost">{{cost}}</p>
                    <hr>
                </div><!-- /.pet -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 7 `.nameNav` elements vs. 39 pets (which means index goes from 0 to 38). `$(".nameNav").eq(index)` -> You see the problem? Hint: [Reminder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

Comment: What you’re doing there doesn’t seem to make the most sense to me … so you are switching out the navigation item’s text content once I scroll past the first seven pets – but your anchors are still pointing to the original targets, so the original `<a href="#Adonis"><p class="nameNav first active">Adonis</p></a>` becomes `<a href="#Adonis"><p class="nameNav first">Hank</p></a>` – and therefor _clicking_ on those navigation items takes me to the wrong place completely. […]

Comment: […] I would not switch out DOM elements for this, but rather have _all_ navigation items be present in the DOM right from the start, and then _display_ only the first seven, the next seven, and so on … making a bit clever use of CSS selectors, this could even be done by simply switching out _one_ class on the parent element.

Comment: @CBroe Could you expand on this with a code sample.

Comment: @Andreas While I had an inkling that I should be using (%) I don't necessarily know where the remainder operator fits into this. Could you explain with a code sample

Comment: You really should follow the path CBroe has mentioned. But nevertheless... `var navElements = $(".nameNav"); navElements.eq(index % navElements.length).addClass("active");`

Comment: @CBroe Let me know how I can make those fixes to have all navigation items in the DOM from the start and only display the first seven.

Comment: Loop through them with JS and set a class to show/hide them dynamically.

Comment: @CBroe Could you show me that with a code sample.